# Error: '$viewMap[...]' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery/Javascript knowledge is limited I'm afraid. I have a "how did you hear about us" dropdown on a form. However, I get the following Javascript error on change:

Error: '$viewMap[...]' is null or not an object

My dropdown looks like this:

```
<select onchange="setSourceID(this.value)" name="sourceID" id="sourceID" class="required">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please choose&#8230;</option>
    <option value="National Paper">National Paper</option>
    <option value="Magazine">Magazine</option>
    <option value="Regional Paper">Regional Paper</option>
    <option value="9682">Internet Search</option>
    <option value="9684">Recommendation</option>
    <option value="9683">Other</option>
</select>

<!-- some additional dropdowns below that appear based on what's selected above -->
<select onchange="setSourceID(this.value)" name="referrerName[]" id="referrer1" class="smartField">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please choose&#8230;</option>
<option value="The Times">The Times</option>
etc...
</select>

and so on...
```

My Javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.smartField').hide();
    $.viewMap = {
        '' : $([]),
        'National Paper' : $('#referrer1'),
        'Magazine' : $('#referrer2'),
        'Regional Paper' : $('#referrer3')
        //'Internet Search' : $('#referrer4'), 
        //'Recommendation' : $('#referrer5'), 
        //'Other' : $('#referrer6')
    };

    $("#sourceID").bind(($.browser.msie ? "click" : "change"), function () {
        $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); }); // hide all
        $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show(); // show current
    });
});
```

Does anybody have any idea where I'm going wrong? Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem lies in this line:

```
$.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
```

Check what `$(this).val()` returns and see if the corresponding key exists in `$.viewMap`

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that? With an alert?

Comment: Yes, an `alert` would suffice, though `console.log` (with Firebug) would be better